# jQuery not appending an element

Tags: jquery, datepicker, append

I'm trying to be ambitious and add additional search boxes to flexigrid...
I've delved into the flexigrid script and found where the search elements are added. I then added my own input field as below:

```
$(g.sDiv).append("<input type='text' value='' size='30' name='fromDate' id='datepicker' class='qsbox datepicker' />");
```

g.sDiv is a variable created as follows earlier in the script:

```
g.sDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

This I assume creates a div and I'm able to append items to it.

A couple of things though I can't work out.
If I append the following element:

```
$(g.sDiv).append("<div id = 'customSearch'></div>");
```

(which does render correctly) and then try to append to that div using:

```
$('#customSearch').append("<input type='text' value='' size='30' name='fromDate' id='datepicker' class='qsbox datepicker' />");
```

The input box is not added to the page.

Why would this method not work?

Also, having created the input box I want to add the datepicker ui. How can I do this to a dynamically created item. I've tried adding this line of code after the element has supposedly been created:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

but this doesn't work.

What am I missing with appending items and how can I then add datepicker to the final input once it's been appended.

Answer (score 5):

You have to first add `g.sDiv` to the document for the `$('#customSearch')` selector to find the element, otherwise the element is not yet part of the document and therefore cannot be found using `document.getElementById()`.

```
$("body").append(g.sDiv);
$("#customSearch").doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought: document.createElement added the item to the page ...it's certainly there and I can append items to g.sDiv without problem. I'm having problems appending items to items I have just appended (if that makes sense) eg once i've appended a div with id customSearch I am unable to append items to the div with the id customSearch.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the id is unique? `alert($("id=[customSearch]").length)`

Comment: Again, the element MUST be part of the dom, for example, a descendant of the `<html />` node. It can't be a detached element.